# How to use multiple RGB cameras with ROS?

Tags: gscam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi dear ROS community!

I would like to learn how to use multiple RGB cameras with ROS in a single PC. I already know how to use a single camera with the gscam package, I can read the video stream in the /camera/image_raw topic.

However, I couldn't find any information about the use of multiple cameras with ROS (let's say 3). I would like to create a node for each camera ( e.g. /camera01/image_raw, /camera02/image_raw, etc.) and then process them separatedly. I don't know if this is possible using gscam.

In general, what is the proper way (good practice) to use multiple RGB cameras with ROS?

Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192954/how-to-use-multiple-rgb-cameras-with-ros?/) by [diegomex](https://answers.ros.org/users/20224/diegomex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-09-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on 2014-09-18**:
I don't know about RGB, but for RGBD it is possible to use multiple Kinects. Look into the openni_launch-package. There you can give each camera it's own namespace, like you proposed in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generally, running multiple copies of the same system is easy enough, since each node has it's own private [namespace](http://wiki.ros.org/Names).

However, having used [gscam](http://wiki.ros.org/gscam), this might be tricky because it's very un-ROS in the way it reads the device name from an environment variable.

If you use [usb_cam](http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam), you should be able to specify the input device for each node with the `video_device` parameter.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0